# What does "putting up" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

I just read a question on Stack Overflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase).

The question starts with:

> I've been somewhat **"putting up"** with GitHub always asking for my username and password when I clone a repository. [...]

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

I searched "put up" but the result only gives:

> construct or erect something.

"I put up the tent and cooked a meal"

Which doesn't seem to fit here. So what does it mean in the context?

Comment: They feel annoyed with this Github process but have to tolerate/accept it.

Answer (score 7):

'Put up **with**' is a phrasal verb.

> put up with
> PHRASAL VERB
> If you put up with something, you tolerate or
> accept it, even though you find it unpleasant or unsatisfactory.

[Put up with (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-up-with)

Comment: Yes, the choice of quotes in the original is somewhat weird.